# Javascript Try Catch for Localstorage Detection

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I'm working on [the Dive Into HTML 5 Tutorial on localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#storage), and came across this piece of code:

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
return false;
  }
}
```

I understand the part about `return 'localStorage' in window`, etc, but what I don't understand is why the need for a try catch statement here? Isn't it enough to simply write the below?

```
function supports_html5_storage(){
return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage']!==null;
}
```

By the way: I do (kind of) know the purpose of try/catch, I'm just wondering what kind of exception can we be possibly expecting?

Comment: Dude... you should read the few lines around the code you post...

Comment: Oh man, unbelievable...I missed that line! Stupid question then, it turns out. My apologies. Thanks everyone for your contribution nonetheless. Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If your browser supports HTML5 storage, there will be a localStorage
>   property on the global window object. If your browser doesn’t support
>   HTML5 storage, the localStorage property will be undefined. Due to an
>   unfortunate bug in older versions of Firefox, this test will raise an
>   exception if cookies are disabled, so the entire test is wrapped in a
>   try..catch statement.

Above text copied from: http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#storage